# How can i get workflow's activities collection from SPWorkflowTemplate?

Tags: 2010, workflow, workflow-activity

I can't find any method or property of SPWorkflowTemplate that returns a activities collection. Also XML representation doesn't contains any references to activities neither. Is there any approach to retrieve them?